# Can power outlet be taken as a current source?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-source, electricity, voltage-source

Consider a situation where I have a power outlet and I am completely unaware of the internal circuits and the fact that the electricity comes from an ac voltage source supplied by some company. I just want to know whether I can take the power outlet as a current source for my device rather than an ac voltage source. In short, what is the property of the power outlet as a black box? I am taking a course in electronics and the difference between a current source and a voltage source is unclear to me.

Comment: *I just want to know whether I can take the power outlet as a current source for my device rather than an ac voltage source* Think about that: suppose your device needs only 0.1 A but the outlet delivers 1 A anyway! What happens then? What happens when you disconnect your device so the 1A has nowhere to go, if the socket had enough voltage available, the current would simply **arc over**. Not a nice situation I think.

Comment: A voltage source is always 9V (for example), a current source is always 1A (for example). Do you know the difference between V and A?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both 'current source' and 'voltage source' as presented in your course in electronics are **idealisations**. They are theoretical entities we never meet in practice. But they are often good approximations to what we do meet, within a certain range.

The difference between them is the output impedance. A voltage source has ideally a zero output impedance. In practice, any source with a small output impedance is well approximated by a voltage source. Its output current can vary from zero to a large output, while its voltage changes by only a small fraction. A current source has an ideally infinite output impedance. The voltage will vary from zero to a large value, while its current changes little.

The power outlet on your wall is best approximated as a voltage source, for most of the things you want to do with it, like connect lighting, heating, motor loads to it. Its output impedance is very low. Within the range of current that it is intended to supply, the voltage drop is small.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer!

Answer (score 2):

> ... and the fact that the electricity comes from an **AC voltage source** supplied by some company.

You have answered your own question with a "No". The network operators do their best to maintain supply voltage as a constant. Current is limited by source resistance and circuit breakers and fuses.

> In short, what is the property of the power outlet as a black box?

It can be idealised as a voltage source with series impedance.

Answer (score 1):

Electric circuit theory says that a voltage source which has some serial impedance as a non-ideality can be substituted by an equivalent current source which has the same impedance in parallel. The rest of the electric circuit wouldn't see any difference.

Let's assume your 230 VAC outlet could output 200 A short circuit current before the wires melt if there were no tripping breakers. The series impedance = 230/200 Ohm = 1,15 Ohm.

The equivalent non-ideal current source would be 200A ideal current source with 1,15 impedance in parallel. Everything connected to that equivalent outlet would see no difference.

The circuit theoretically equivalent behaviour doesn't mean that producing the current source based 230 VAC outlet needs equivalent construction effort. We do not have practical electricity production methods which tend to produce certain current and high currents would cause high losses in practical wires.

But we still tried to construct 230 VAC outlet. What if the whole electricity system including the production, distribution and construction of electric devices were based on constant current (assuming a practical constant current generator exists)?

There should be overvoltage breakers which short the circuit if a fault somewhere breaks a wire. New electric devices would be put in series with the already connected ones. Nothing unimaginable there.

Unfortunately I have grown up with the constant voltage system. I have no collection to pick principles from to create common device functionalities that people expect. I do not know if electronic components could be created with the constant current idea?  The semiconductor theory starts with electronvolts. I haven't checked if someone in our sister site https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com has an idea.

I guess the continuous energy loss in practical conductive materials would trash the whole idea as well in component-, device-, system- and infrastructure levels. But low cost superconductors would help substantially.